# FM Tuner for iPod Touch

Tags: iphone, ipod-touch

Is there a way to add (or even enable) a FM tuner for the iPod Touch? The only thing stopping me from getting one is the missing FM tuner. By the way, I need the FM tuner to listen to TV shows at the gym (they transmit the sound through a FM transmitter). So I cannot replace the FM tuner by Pandora.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know for sure whether the fourth generation iPod actually has a built in FM Tuner. However, [external FM Tuner adapters](http://www.griffintechnology.com/products/ifm) are quite prevalent.

**Edit**: Whoops, sorry about that, I did link the wrong item. Chops is correct, that was a transmitter. The link now points to the original item I had intended to link.

Comment: The current crop of iPod touches don't support an inbuilt receiver (although they physically have all the necessary chipsets to do that, it's been disabled by Apple). Just beware, it's a tuner/receiver that's being asked, not a transmitter. There are also available on the market, best to check what works best with the latest Touches - something like this: http://store.apple.com/us/product/TU825VC/A?mco=MTY3ODQ5OTY